# Adding values to new attribute field fails

Tags: pyqgis, features

I have written some code to edit layers in my QGIS project. I now added a new attribute field to my output layer and want to add values to it, which I calculated within the script. Each value is linked to a specific ID in the table of the output layer. I tried many things, but the new attribute field stays empty somehow.

This is the specific section of my code, where I try to add the values to the new field:

```
output_lyr.startEditing()
output_lyr.addAttribute(QgsField('EW_new', QVariant.Double))



# Iteriere durch die GEB_ID-Listen und berechne EW_new-Werte
for geb_id, feature_ids in geb_id_lists.items():
    num_elements = len(feature_ids)
    
    
    # Überprüfen, ob die GEB_ID im Dictionary "geb_id_to_ew" existiert
    if geb_id in geb_id_to_ew:
        ew_value = geb_id_to_ew[geb_id]
        
        # Überprüfen, ob "EW" nicht 0 ist, bevor die Berechnung ausgeführt wird
        if num_elements != 0:
            result = ew_value / num_elements
            
            
            # Den berechneten Wert in das Feld "EW_new" schreiben
            for feature_id in feature_ids:
                output_lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feature_id: {output_lyr.fields().indexFromName('EW_new'): result}})
        else:
            # Wenn num_elements gleich 0 ist, wird ein Platzhalterwert eingefügt
               
            for feature_id in feature_ids:
                output_lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feature_id: {output_lyr.fields().indexFromName('EW_new'): 0}})


# Speichern Sie die Änderungen im Layer
output_lyr.updateFields()
output_lyr.commitChanges()
```

This is the whole code:

```
# Lädt alle notwendigen Bibliotheken (libaries) in das Skript
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsField
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

#Greift auf das aktuelle GIS Projekt zu
project = QgsProject.instance()

#Definiert Namen in Python für die jeweiligen Layer im Projekt. 
fpg = project.mapLayersByName('FPG_cut')[0]
wgf = project.mapLayersByName('WGF_cut')[0]

output_lyr = QgsVectorLayer(f'Point?crs={fpg.crs().authid()}', 'FPG_count', 'memory')
output_lyr.dataProvider().addAttributes(fpg.fields())
output_lyr.updateFields()

# Feld das gesammelt werden soll
field_name = 'GEB_ID'

# Python dictionary um die IDs zu sammeln 
geb_id_lists = {}

# Iteriert durch die features des Punkte Layers
for feature in fpg.getFeatures():
    geb_id = feature[field_name]
    if geb_id not in geb_id_lists:
        geb_id_lists[geb_id] = []
    geb_id_lists[geb_id].append(feature.id())

# Zähle und drucke die Anzahl der Listen
print(f"Number of unique 'GEB_ID' lists: {len(geb_id_lists)}")



# Sortieren und Filtern jeder Liste nach den Feldern "LDEN", "VAR" und "FPG".
for geb_id, feature_ids in geb_id_lists.items():
    # Sortieren nach dem Feld "LDEN" in absteigender Reihenfolge - buggy
    sorted_feature_ids = sorted(feature_ids, key=lambda id: fpg.getFeature(id)['LDEN'], reverse=False)
    
    # Filter nach "VAR"-Feld (nur "+" behalten) und "FPG"-Feld (nur "Wohngeb" behalten)
    filtered_feature_ids = [id for id in sorted_feature_ids if fpg.getFeature(id)['VAR'] == '+' and fpg.getFeature(id)['FPG'] == 'Wohngeb']
    
    geb_id_lists[geb_id] = filtered_feature_ids



# Feststellen, ob die Anzahl der Werte gerade oder ungerade ist
for geb_id, feature_ids in geb_id_lists.items():
    count = len(feature_ids)
    if count % 2 == 1:   # Wenn die Anzahl ungerade ist, wird der kleinste Wert entfernt. Hier der erste Wert weil die Liste mit den kleinsten Werten beginnt.
        feature_ids.remove(geb_id_lists[geb_id][0])

# Entfernen Sie die untere Hälfte der Werte aus jeder Liste.
for geb_id, feature_ids in geb_id_lists.items():
    count = len(feature_ids)
    if count > 1:  # Mindestens ein Wert bleibt in der Liste
        half_index = count // 2
        geb_id_lists[geb_id] = feature_ids[half_index:]




# Verteilung der Bewohner auf die verbleibende größere Hälfte des Hauses

# Annahme: Der Vektorlayer "FPG_count" wurde bereits erstellt, und das Feld "EW_new" ist vorhanden.



output_lyr.startEditing()
output_lyr.addAttribute(QgsField('EW_new', QVariant.Double))



# Iteriere durch die GEB_ID-Listen und berechne EW_new-Werte
for geb_id, feature_ids in geb_id_lists.items():
    num_elements = len(feature_ids)
    
    
    # Überprüfen, ob die GEB_ID im Dictionary "geb_id_to_ew" existiert
    if geb_id in geb_id_to_ew:
        ew_value = geb_id_to_ew[geb_id]
        
        # Überprüfen, ob "EW" nicht 0 ist, bevor die Berechnung ausgeführt wird
        if num_elements != 0:
            result = ew_value / num_elements
            
            
            # Den berechneten Wert in das Feld "EW_new" schreiben
            for feature_id in feature_ids:
                output_lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feature_id: {output_lyr.fields().indexFromName('EW_new'): result}})
        else:
            # Wenn num_elements gleich 0 ist, wird ein Platzhalterwert eingefügt
               
            for feature_id in feature_ids:
                output_lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feature_id: {output_lyr.fields().indexFromName('EW_new'): 0}})


# Speichern Sie die Änderungen im Layer
output_lyr.updateFields()
output_lyr.commitChanges()


# Grenzwert
threshold_lden = 55

# Punkte mit "LDEN"-Werten unterhalb des Schwellenwerts herausfiltern
for geb_id, feature_ids in geb_id_lists.items():
    feature_ids = [id for id in feature_ids if fpg.getFeature(id)['LDEN'] >= threshold_lden]
    geb_id_lists[geb_id] = feature_ids


# Fügen Sie die Merkmale zur Ergebnisebene hinzu.
for geb_id, feature_ids in geb_id_lists.items():
    for feature_id in feature_ids:
        output_lyr.dataProvider().addFeatures([fpg.getFeature(feature_id)])

# Berechnen Sie die Gesamtzahl der Punkte in der Ausgabeschicht.
num_points_output_layer = output_lyr.featureCount()

# Druckt die Gesamtzahl der Punkte
print(f"Total number of points in the output layer: {num_points_output_layer}")



project.addMapLayer(output_lyr)

# Aktualisiert die Karte
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

Comment: Whta is the `geb_id_to_ew`, a list ?

Comment: I highly recommend reading this article: [PyQGIS 101: Creating & editing a new vector layer](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/)

Comment: Thank you, the article is very well written. Even with the exact code from the article (adjusted to my output layer's name) I cannot fill the field with values or the "Hello World!" from the article.

Comment: geb_id_to_ew is a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should avoid mixing dataProvider()-methods with editing your layer.
`output_lyr.dataProvider().addFeatures([fpg.getFeature(feature_id)])`
will change the feature directly in the provider, no need to commit anything. Then your final `output_lyr.commitChanges()` will overide the changes you did before with the direct provider calls. so anything is like before without any changes...
you should use somthing like:

```
with edit(layer):
    layer.addFeature(...)
    layer.updateFeatures(...)
```

Comment: So deleting the "output_lyr.commitChanges()" line should fix it? I tried and the attribute field is still empty.

Comment: don't use dataProvider()-methods, just work on the editable layer and use commit at the end.